# Does DataApi.getDataItems retrieve data from the local datastore or does it always hit the network?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I would think it would just ask the local datastore on the device, but the [docs say](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html#getDataItems(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)):

> Retrieves all DataItems matching the provided Uri, from the Android Wear network

It's not clear exactly what "from the Android Wear network" means.  Does this mean it always goes out to the network to ask for the latest data?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the *"Android Wear network"* is simply an euphemism for the shared storage between the handheld and the wearable. Since Google Play Services automatically keeps these data stores synced, it's likely that actually querying the current device is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

first you must know that, Wear and Phone share a DataItem Queue, when you put a DataItem into wearable api, the dataItem will be put into the queue, and then sync to both or more side, so when you get dataItem from local, it just need to get from the queue which exist on google play service run in the device, because the queue is synced every time